# Use IoC-container as service locator to some service to get oppotunity create sub scope

Tags: c#, ioc-container, dryioc

I want use `DryIoC` as service locator, ie inject container instance to some service to get oppotunity create sub scope.

```
internal abstract class BaseService<TEntity, T> : IDisposable
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<T>
    where T : notnull
{
    **protected bool isParallel = false;**

    protected DataContext Context
        => **this.isParallel
         ? this.resolver.Value.Resolve<DataContext>()
         :** this.current.Context;

    **private readonly Lazy<IResolverContext> resolver;**

    **private bool IsReadOnly => this.isParallel;**

    protected BaseService(**IContainer container,** ICurrentDataContext current, IDeletingStrategy<TEntity> delete)
    {
        this.strategies =
            new ()
            {
                Delete = delete
            };

        **this.resolver = new Lazy<IResolverContext>(() => container.OpenScope());**

        this.current = current;
    }

    private void ReadOnlyCheck()
    {
        **if (this.IsReadOnly)
        {
            throw
              new NotSupportedException("ToDo");
        }**
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (this.wasDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            **this.resolver.Value.Dispose();**
        }

        this.wasDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

When I call any of CRUD methods, the following exception is thrown:

> DryIoc.ContainerException: "code: Error.ContainerIsDisposed;
> message: Container is disposed and should not be used: "container with scope {IsDisposed=true, Name=null}
> with Rules with {TrackingDisposableTransients} and without {ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient, VariantGenericTypesInResolvedCollection}
> with FactorySelector=SelectLastRegisteredFactory
> with Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments, PropertiesAndFields=} has been DISPOSED!
> You may include Dispose stack-trace into the message via:
> container.With(rules => rules.WithCaptureContainerDisposeStackTrace())""

But if I remove **bold** elements it works.

Comment: There is a lot of code here to find the problem. Could remove the non relevant code. `Lazy<IResolverContext>` looks fishy to me. It is stateful instance of context which is unbound from the scopes lifetime. DryIoc will automatically inject the correct IResolverContext instamce inside the scope, so better not hold on it.

Comment: @dadhi non relevant code removed

Answer (score 0):

It is still hard to find the problem based on just the code provided.

I would guess that the `container` argument passed to `BaseService` constructor and used to lazily create the scoped resolver is disposed by the time when you're trying to create the actual resolver.

Also, the container passed to the `BaseMessage` is already the scoped container per the exception message, and maybe it is not what you are expecting.

You may add the rule `container.With(rules => rules.WithCaptureContainerDisposeStackTrace())` mentioned in the exception to get the actual place where the container is being disposed.